# Errors showing up interrupt typing when using zod and react-hook-forms in typescript application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, zod

I'm trying to make an registration page for users and using react-hook-forms for the registration form and zod for validation. When I'm testing the form, at first I can type whatever and the errors only show up after submitting. However, after this the errors keep interrupting the typing as for example the password input interrupts when I get eight characters and again when I type in a number. This also happens with email's input too with its respective message error.

My react-hook-forms is set with on { mode: "onSubmit" }. This is my code below

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { z } from "zod";
import RegisterSchema from "../components/Authentication/Register/RegisterSchema";
import { AuthTitle } from "../components/Authentication";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";

type RegisterSchemaType = z.infer<typeof RegisterSchema>

type FormFieldProps = {
  labelText: string;
  inputText: string;
  registerInput: keyof RegisterSchemaType;
};

const Register = () => {

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm<RegisterSchemaType>({ resolver: zodResolver(RegisterSchema), mode: "onSubmit"});

  const onSubmit = (data: RegisterSchemaType) => {
    console.log(data);
  }; 

  console.log(errors);

  const FormFields = ({ labelText, inputText, registerInput } : FormFieldProps) => (
    <div className='flex flex-col'>
      <label className='uppercase text-[#49A078] text-sm sm:text-md' htmlFor={inputText}>
        {labelText}
      </label>
      <div className="flex flex-col relative">
        <input
          {...register(registerInput)}
          className='mb-1 mt-1 p-3 outline-1 outline-[#263228] outline rounded-sm pr-5 focus:outline-[#49A078] focus:outline-2'
        />
        {errors[registerInput] && (
          <span className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-0 mb-4">{errors[registerInput]?.message}</span>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col h-screen justify-center items-center">
      <AuthTitle title="Trace" subTitle="Register" />

      <div className="flex md:flex-row flex-col">
        <form className="flex flex-col p-5 pr-8 border-r border-gray-400" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <FormFields labelText="First Name" inputText="firstName" registerInput="firstName"/>
          <FormFields labelText="Surname" inputText="surname" registerInput="surname"/>
          <FormFields labelText="Email Address" inputText="email" registerInput="email"/>
          <FormFields labelText="Password" inputText="password" registerInput="password"/>
          <button className="bg-[#263228] text-white p-3 rounded-sm uppercase mt-3" type="submit">
            Register
          </button>
        </form>

        {/* OAuth buttons */}
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center p-4">
          {/* Google OAuth */}
          {/* You may need to replace this with the appropriate library */}
          <h1>LOREM IPSUM</h1>

          {/* Apple OAuth */}
          {/* Add Apple OAuth button here */}
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Bottom link */}
      <div className="mt-auto">
        <p className="text-center text-[#49A078] uppercase">Already have an account?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

This is my RegisterSchema

```
import { z } from "zod";

const RegisterSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string().email({message: "Invalid email."}),
  firstName: z.string().min(2, {message: "Must be 2 or more characters long."}),
  surname: z.string().min(2, {message: "Must be 2 or more characters long."}),
  password: z.string()
    .min(8, {message: "Must be 8 or more characters long."})
    .refine((password) => /\d/.test(password), {message: 'Must contain at least 1 number.',})
});

export default RegisterSchema;
```

Is there a way to make the errors not interrupt the input field typing? I've looked at react-hook-forms online and when the errors show up for them, the input field is still typable.

I've tried different modes for useForm method as well as a State variable for React, none of which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use it like this in my project and never had that problem. See that i only apply the value and on change handler to the input

```js
import { TextField as MuiTextField } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { useController as useFieldController } from "react-hook-form";

import { useFormControllerContext } from "@bujus/common-frontend";

const TextField = ({ isAutofocusing = false, isEnabled = true, label, name, type }) => {
    const formController = useFormControllerContext();

    const fieldController = useFieldController({
        control: formController.control,
        name,
    });

    return (
        <MuiTextField
            autoFocus={isAutofocusing}
            disabled={!isEnabled}
            error={fieldController.fieldState.error !== undefined}
            fullWidth
            {...(fieldController.fieldState.error === undefined
                ? {}
                : { helperText: fieldController.fieldState.error.message })}
            label={label}
            onChange={fieldController.field.onChange}
            {...(type === undefined ? {} : { type })}
            value={fieldController.field.value}
        />
    );
};

export { TextField };
```

```js
import { useForm as useFormController } from "react-hook-form";

    const formController = useFormController({
        mode: "onChange",
        resolver: joiResolver(helperValidationSchemas.update.form, validationOptions),
        defaultValues: {
            username: helper.username,
        },
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, turns out it was my errors[registerInput] was the thing causing it. I don't know why but thank you for letting me pinpoint it.